# Given longitude and latitude, how to find country

Tags: geolocation, gps, latitude-longitude

If I have a latitude and longitude, how do I find out the country of that location.. 
If found out about [Google Reverse Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding), but unfortunately, it requires the service to be used along with Google Maps, which is not my case..

Is there a static database or something which I can refer to?   It would be better if I have a static database as opposed to a service..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a service, it is a lot of work.

First, you need the country polygons with assigned country codes. One country will have on average approx 50.000 vertices.

Then it's a simple point-in-polygon search.

Use a spatial index to limit the country polygon to search.
It becomes a bit more difficult if you have to consider enclaves.

Comment: Thanks! I actually found this kml file [here](http://www.gelib.com/maps/world-borders.kmz)..  That is what you meant by polygon data,right?

Comment: Not bad! this is useable, but at the borders it is not acurate, of course.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Bing Maps Api, it doesn't require displaying maps as far as I know,

```
http://dev.virtualearth.net/services/v1/geocodeservice/geocodeservice.asmx/ReverseGeocode?latitude=22.98&longitude=35.43637&key=[YOU_KEY]&culture=%22en-us%22&format=json
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [geonames.org](http://www.geonames.org) ["Country code / reverse geocoding"](http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html#countrycode) webservice, for example:

http://api.geonames.org/countryCode?lat=47.03&lng=10.2&username=demo 
-> `AT`

Comment: GeoNames service is great, but it has API limitations, though. 2000 requests per day per registered user id.